# Is it possible to covert CGRect into CGPathRef ? - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cgpath, cgpathref

I have a `CGRect` based on that I want to make `CGPathRef`.

Is it doable in objective C?

Comment: A `CGRect` is a Rectangle. You can create a `CGPath` following the rectangle.

Comment: @Larme how can I do this ? Not able to find any source.

Comment: `CGPathCreateWithRect()`? Then there should be a bridge `CGPath` <=> `CGPathRef`

Comment: @Larme Thnks. Let me try this.

Comment: @Larme is it possible to create CGPath from UIImage ?

Comment: Define " create CGPath from UIImage", because I'm afraid that won't be what you want. Else, a `UIImage`, has a `size` and `scale` property. It's easy to get a `CGRect` equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 1, y: 2, width: 3, height: 4)
let path = CGPath(rect: bounds, transform: nil)
```